# How can i get only human signature draw on an image selected from gallery or camera in android

Tags: android

for example if i select this image from image gallery now
 i want to get only the signature in blue color and then set into image view and want to remove all
 color and background.is there any library for it and how can i do
 this.? if picture changes always i need only signature

[see image here](https://www.shutterstock.com/de/image-photo/handwritten-signature-official-document-school-55776109?src=OmJA8X-5aTB6MM4-kcPVAA-1-32)